# Prefix tree problem

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to manage with nearly 1,300,000 words (some groups of words are similar).
I'm doing something like small vocabulary, where each word has its description.
The fast search through vocabulary is need. So I decided to use prefix tree.
Firstly the preffix tree is needed to build up (it's a slow process, I know that), after this fast surf through vocabulary might be organised.

But my problem - that preffix tree is building extremly slow (first 300,000 words builds up fast, but building of tail is very very slow, so slow that I couldn't wait until tree is build!!).

Here is my prefix tree class:

```
public class InverseVocabularyTree implements Serializable 
{
    private HashMap<Character, InverseVocabularyTree> childs;
    private String description; 

    public InverseVocabularyTree() {        
        childs=new HashMap<Character, InverseVocabularyTree>();     
    }

    public void addWord(String word, String description){       
        InverseVocabularyTree tr=this;      
        InverseVocabularyTree chld=this;
        char[] letters=word.toCharArray();
        for (int i=word.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {        
            if (!tr.childs.containsKey(letters[i]))
            {               
                for(int j=i; j>=0; j--) //a small optimisation..
                {
                    chld=new InverseVocabularyTree();
                    tr.childs.put(letters[j], chld);
                    tr=chld;
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            tr=tr.childs.get(letters[i]);
        }
        tr.description=description;         
        return;
    }

    public HashMap<Character, InverseVocabularyTree> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }

    public String[] getRemovableBasicParts() {
        return removableBasicParts;
    }

    public LinkedList<String[]> getAllRemovableBasicParts() {
        LinkedList<String[]> ret=new LinkedList<String[]>();
        if (removableBasicParts!=null)
            ret.add(removableBasicParts);
        if (childs.keySet().isEmpty())
            return ret;
        for(char c : childs.keySet())
            ret.addAll(childs.get(c).getAllRemovableBasicParts());
        return ret;
    }   
}
```

So, has anybody some ideas or advices how to optimize in this situation?

Comment: The methods getRemovableBasicParts() and getAllRemovableBasicParts() are superfluous.

Comment: Did you check for garbage collector effects?

Comment: Yes, if user ask vocabulary to get description of some word, that not in vocabulary - program will show him most similar word (so it looks like fuzzy search..) and prefix tree solve this problem good (I hoope :)

Comment: Yes...after every 100,000 words I call System.gc()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a NavigableMap or similar Set if you don't need a value.
Say you need to search for words startign with "abc" you just need to do

```
NavigableMap<String, Boolean> wordmap = new TreeMap<String, Boolean>();
Random random = new Random(1);
for(int i=0;i<10*1000*1000;i++)
    wordmap.put(Long.toString(Math.abs(random.nextLong()), 36).substring(1), true);
String prefix = "abcd";
for (String word : wordmap.subMap(prefix, prefix+"\uffff").keySet()) {
    System.out.println(word + " starts with " + prefix);
}
```

// or

```
for (String word : wordmap.tailMap(prefix).keySet()) {
    if (!word.startsWith(prefix)) break;
    System.out.println(word + " starts with " + prefix);
}
```

This uses 1GB on my machine for 10 million entries and prints

```
abcd0krpbk1 starts with abcd
abcd7xi05pe starts with abcd
abcdlw4pwfl starts with abcd
```

EDIT: based on the feed back I would suggest something like following approach.

```
// keys stored in reverse order of the original string.
NavigableMap<String, Boolean> wordmap
String search = "dcba";
// retains hte order keys were added.
Map<String, Boolean> results = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();
for(int i=search.size();i>=1;i--) {
    String s = search.substring(0, i);
    results.putAll(wordmap.subMap(s, s+'\uFFFF')); // ignores duplicates
}
```

The results will have the combined of all the searches in order they were added, from most specific to least specific.
    }

Comment: The trick is to use tailMap(), headMap() or subMap() as approriate. I could have used subMap, will add this to the example.

Comment: What do you mean "if you don't need a value"? For each word he needs to store a description

Comment: @Christina, Just making the point that this approach works with NavigableSet as well. In this case a NavigableMap is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Christina and @Peter Lawrey - Thanks for your advices :) in fact - what i need is: when user input "abcdefg" I need to show all wards that starts with "abcdefg", and "abcdef", and "abcde" etc.

Comment: @stemm So unless I'm missing something your current implementation won't work. For the word abcdefg you're putting in the tree g->f->e->d->c->b->a so how are you going to find abcdef or abcde? Are you going to do a separate tree traversal for each one of those words?

Comment: @Christina in fact I'm creating inverse vocabulary. For my application most important to find words which have similar endings - for example "clipboard" and "keyboard" in inverse representation looks like "draobpilc" and "draobyek" and in such representation they have joint part "draob" also the word "forward" in reverse looks like "drawrof" so if user looks for word which ends with *ard he would get "clipboard","keyboard","blackboard","forward" etc.

Comment: And only one marching through tree nodes could give all theese words.

Comment: @stemm, you are right that if you need word endings, you would need to either write the works backward or write your on Comparator<String> which would compare Strings from the end.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, so, in my situation (for example word "abcd") I have to get all words from NavigableMap using wordmap.tailMap("dcba").keySet(), then get all words using wordmap.tailMap("cba").keySet(), then wordmap.tailMap("ba").keySet() and wordmap.tailMap("a").keySet() or there is much simple solution?

Comment: True, however the last tailMap("a") will have all the entries from others as well. Not sure what is the benifit of taking all of these combinations is. In fact it may be faster to take the tailMap("a") first and from this take the tailMap("ab") etc.

Comment: ohh...I've mistake))) I mean wordmap.tailMap("dcba").keySet() + wordmap.tailMap("dcb").keySet() + wordmap.tailMap("dc").keySet() + wordmap.tailMap("d").keySet(). In my application, the words, which have longer joint part has higher weight.

Comment: @stemm, I believe I have a simple way to calculate this, see my edit. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the problem is that after a few hundred thousand words your tree is getting too tall you could try to use certain commonly encountered bi-grams or tri-grams instead of single letters for a couple of nodes in order to make it a bit shorter. For example if you have a lot of words ending in "ing" instead of having one node for g who has a child for n who has a child for i you could create a single node for ing. Of course how good this will work depends on your vocabulary and you'll probably need to do some analysis to find appropriate bi-, tri-grams to use.

In general, since you say you have checked garbage collection I think it would be usefull if you could find out if there is a specific tree size after which your application starts slowing down or of the problem is something entirely different. Having a better view of what exactly the problem is could give you new ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll profile my application. And about bigramms, I've tried something like that, but application still slow... Hm...and what about java heap? Maybe there some trouble? hm..or, I've idea about jvm option just in time compilation, maybe it helps...

Comment: @stemm Yes, the problem could be the heap or anything else unrelated to your structure, that's why I proposed to try and find what is going on in there. Of course as a quick test you could always try a run giving the JVM more heap space and see how that's going.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you're right about bi-grams and tri-grams. In fact there're really where problems with size of cache in my application, so the solve was -Xmx. But right now is time to optimize algorithm and try to compare this variant with NavigableMaps.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating at least one HashMap for every word (often more) - so if you have really many different words, you run out of memory. Don't explicitly call `System.gc`, instead observer your program with `jconsole` or a similar profiler tool.

I suppose that after your first 300000 words simply the memory is nearly full, and your program spends most of its time trying to get more space. If this is the case, try to give your program more memory (with the `-Xmx` option).

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing it. And maybe would be good to set jvm option just in time compilation?